# Htaccess rewriting URL's in directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My Wordpress website has blog posts with urls that look like: www.domain.com/blog/blog-name

A lot of my website users are going to www.domain.com/blog-name, without the blog directory in the path. This is because I recently changed the ways my url works.

I would like to do a 403 redirect or an htaccess rewrite... whichever is the proper way to direct my users to the proper path.

How would I do this and only affect my blog posts and not other pages on my website?

So www.domain.com/contact remains the same, but any blog posts like www.domain.com/blog-post will get redirected to www.domain.com/blog/blog-name

My current HTACCESS file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: 403 is an error code (Forbidden). I think you're looking for 301 (Moved Permanently) or 303 (See Other), depending on if the page can move. See [list of status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Answer (score 0):

Login to your WordPress admin.

Go to Settings --> Permalinks.

Under 'Custom Structure' change it to /blog/%postname%/

This will only add the blog base to posts (not pages etc) which is exactly what you need.

Comment: I did this already. What I need to redirect users who still go to www.domain.com/blog-name to my new url structure which is www.domain.com/blog/blog-name